# WikiData SPARQL times out with subquery + labels service + OPTIONAL

Tags: subquery, sparql, wikidata

While trying to answer this question: [How to filter results of wikidata to specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413677/how-to-filter-results-of-wikidata-to-specific-language/50517526#50517526) , I have encountered the following problem:

Some countries have [more than one capital](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%28COUNT%28%2a%29%20as%20%3Fcount%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP36%20%3Fcapital.%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%7D%20%23%20not%20a%20former%20country%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%0AHAVING%20%28COUNT%28%2a%29%20%3E%201%29%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcountryLabel%0A%0ALIMIT%201000).  This query randomly chooses only one capital per country:

```
SELECT ?country (sample(?capital) as ?aCapital) WHERE {
    ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078.  
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3024240} # not a former country
    ?country wdt:P36 ?capital.
} 
GROUP BY ?country
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%28sample%28%3Fcapital%29%20as%20%3FaCapital%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078.%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%7D%20%23%20not%20a%20former%20country%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP36%20%3Fcapital.%0A%7D%20%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry%20%0A)

However, while trying to add labels and coordinates, the query times out:

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?aCapital ?aCapitalLabel ?coords WHERE {
  OPTIONAL {?aCapital wdt:P625 ?coords.}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  {
    SELECT ?country (sample(?capital) as ?aCapital) WHERE {
    ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078.  
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3024240} # not a former country
    ?country wdt:P36 ?capital.
  } 
  GROUP BY ?country 
}
                    }
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
LIMIT 1000
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3FaCapital%20%3FaCapitalLabel%20%3Fcoords%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3FaCapital%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoords.%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%28sample%28%3Fcapital%29%20as%20%3FaCapital%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078.%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%7D%20%23%20not%20a%20former%20country%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP36%20%3Fcapital.%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry%20%0A%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcountryLabel%0ALIMIT%201000)

Comment: And what is the question now? Yes, some queries time out because they are pretty expensive and the Wikidata service is a public service shared across people and there is a timeout set to avoid blocking the service.

Comment: By the way, your second query doesn't make any sense. `OPTIONAL` is a left-join. But before this `OPTIONAL`, you have no other triple pattern, thus, the result will be empty.

Comment: To question is how to add the coords and labels to the simple subquery

Comment: Is there a way to add the subquery before optional?

Comment: Just put it before the `OPTIONAL` I'd say.

Comment: Did you check the sub-query itself? does it also timeout?

Comment: Look at the question. The subquery is simple and does not timeout with 200 results.

Comment: As I said, just put the `OPTIONAL` **after the sub-query** - this works as expected and doesn't timeout. For `OPTIONAL`, the order matters because it'S technically a left-join and evaluation

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I thought this was impossible, but following your comment, I realized that a subquery **BEFORE** `OPTIONAL` requires an additional `{` `}`.  Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Following the comments By @AKSW Above - `OPTIONAL` in SPARQL is a **left** join.

Reordering the subquery and OPTIONAL solves the problem:

```
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?aCapital ?aCapitalLabel ?coords WHERE {
  {
    {
      SELECT ?country (sample(?capital) as ?aCapital) WHERE {
      ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3624078.  
      FILTER NOT EXISTS {?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3024240} # not a former country
      ?country wdt:P36 ?capital.
    } 
    GROUP BY ?country 
  }
  OPTIONAL {?aCapital wdt:P625 ?coords.}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
                    }
ORDER BY ?countryLabel
LIMIT 1000
```

[Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3FaCapital%20%3FaCapitalLabel%20%3Fcoords%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%28sample%28%3Fcapital%29%20as%20%3FaCapital%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078.%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%7D%20%23%20not%20a%20former%20country%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP36%20%3Fcapital.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fcountry%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3FaCapital%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoords.%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FcountryLabel%0ALIMIT%201000).

Please note that this requires adding an additional `{` + `}` to keep the syntax correct.

See also: [SPARQL Optional query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131365/sparql-optional-query)